# I do not know why I keep on getting strange feedback when I am trying to format phone numbers from a user in java.

Tags: java

Whenever I type in a phone number, this program below that I wrote to format phone numbers from the user gives me back weird numbers that I did not even enter at all. Can someone please explain to me why I am getting such weird errors?

I want it so when someone enters just 12345678978  it will format to 1-234-567-8978
If they enter 2345678978 it will format to 234-567-8978
And if they enter 5678978 it will change to 567-8978.
I always get weird numbers that sometimes aren't even what I entered like 
12345678978 I get 144-34--567-
2345678978 I get 153-567-8978
5678978 I get 162-8978

I would really appreciate some help. Thanks.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Test3 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner y = new Scanner(System.in);
    String phoneNumber;
    int phoneNumberLength;
    System.out.print
        ("Please enter your phone number WITHOUT spaces or dashes: ");
    phoneNumber = y.nextLine();
    phoneNumberLength = phoneNumber.length();
    if (phoneNumberLength == 11) {
        phoneNumber = phoneNumber.charAt(0) + "-" + phoneNumber.charAt(1)
            + phoneNumber.charAt(2)
            + phoneNumber.charAt(3)
            + "-" + phoneNumber.charAt(4) + phoneNumber.charAt(5)
            + phoneNumber.charAt(6)
            + "-" + phoneNumber.charAt(7) + phoneNumber.charAt(8)
            + phoneNumber.charAt(9)
            + phoneNumber.charAt(10);
    }
    if (phoneNumberLength == 7) {
        phoneNumber = phoneNumber.charAt(0) + phoneNumber.charAt(1)
            + phoneNumber.charAt(2)
            + "-" + phoneNumber.charAt(3) + phoneNumber.charAt(4)
            + phoneNumber.charAt(5) + phoneNumber.charAt(6);
    }
    else {
        phoneNumber = phoneNumber.charAt(0) + phoneNumber.charAt(1)
            + phoneNumber.charAt(2)
            + "-" + phoneNumber.charAt(3) + phoneNumber.charAt(4)
            + phoneNumber.charAt(5)
            + "-" + phoneNumber.charAt(6) + phoneNumber.charAt(7)
            + phoneNumber.charAt(8)
            + phoneNumber.charAt(9);
    }
    System.out.println("So your phone number is " + phoneNumber + "?");
}
```

By the way. I know it is not formatted correctly but I am very confused with how stackoverflow allows you to add code.

Comment: No. I just wanted to write a program for fun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any string that starts like this:

```
number = number.charAt(0) + number.charAt(1) + ...
```

will cause the problem, because you are adding two `char` types together. This is treated as integer arithmetic, not string concatenation. It would be a lot better to add substrings together, so that the operator is string concatenation, instead of integer addition.

```
number = number.substring(0, 3) + '-' + number.substring(3, 6) + ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Java is converting the characters from your charAt() calls to numerical values. Use substring methods instead, e.g.

```
phoneNumber = phoneNumber.substring(0, 3) + "-" + phoneNumber.substring(3);
```